# What's the difference between these Asus socket 1155 motherboards?

Tags: motherboard, computer-building, specifications, ivy-bridge

I've looked on Asus's website, but they don't make it easy to understand what the differences are, and there's so many models to choose from! It's all spiel, and endless specs. How is anybody supposed to rifle through so much detail in order to make note of minor differences?

If anyone already has this knowledge, I'd love to know what the major differences between these Z77 models are:

1. P8Z77-V
2. P8Z77-V DELUXE
3. P8Z77-V LE
4. P8Z77-V LE PLUS
5. P8Z77-V LK
6. P8Z77-V LX
7. P8Z77-V PREMIUM
8. P8Z77-V PRO
9. P8Z77-V PRO/THUNDERBOLT

Asus are famous for offering lots of solutions, but if there's no easy way to see the differences, how can you even consider what to buy? Their website does include a Comparison tool, but it's broken:

[image]

I'm primarily interested in 1, 3, 4, 5 and 6, if that makes the task any easier.

I'm sure there are people who have this knowledge.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: ASUS does have [product comparison tool](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VdRUY.png) – I was able to look up almost all motherboards. I'm not too sure this question is such a good fit for Super User if you could look up the specs on the website. Everybody else will have to do the same.

Comment: Sadly, their comparison tool [doesn't work properly](http://i784.photobucket.com/albums/yy129/ThunderPeel2001/Uhuh.png). Their website is a mess. I need someone who can explain the differences in plain English :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A comparison of the ASUS P877 - V, -V LE, -V LE PLUS, -V LK and -V LX (your 1,3,4,5 and 6) as described by seller. The other obvious difference by type is price.

[image: ASUS COMP1]
[image: ASUS COMP2]

Answer (score 2):

Well, I've managed to found out some answers, after digging around more.

The difference between the P8Z77-V LE and P8Z77-V LE PLUS is that the PLUS version supports 3-Way Crossfire/SLI. Otherwise they're identical. This is reflected in their Expansion Slots:

**P8Z77-V LE** (and **V LX**)
1 x PCIe 3.0/2.0 x16
1 x PCIe 2.0 x16 (x4 mode)
2 x PCIe 2.0 x1
3 x PCI

**P8Z77-V LE PLUS** (and **V** and **V LK**)
2 x PCIe 3.0/2.0 x16 (x16 or dual x8)
1 x PCIe 2.0 x16 (x4 mode)
2 x PCIe 2.0 x1
2 x PCI

The **V LX** doesn't have a HDMI output for its onboard GFX, whereas the **V**, **V LE**, **V LE PLUS** and **V LK** do.